# featured images - custom links

Tags: customization, images, links

I'm using the Fusion Elegant Theme, but am having an issues with the featured slider.

I added custom "read more" links for my slides. However, where a featured image is assigned, clicking on that image does not link to my specified custom link, but merely navigates to the featured post.

I have posted what I believe to be the relevant code below.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
et_get_option('fusion_feat_pages') ),
                            'posts_per_page'    => (int) $featured_num
                        )
                )   
            );
        }

        while ( $featured_query->have_posts() ) : $featured_query->the_post();
            $post_id            = get_the_ID();

            $bg = et_get_option( 'fusion_bg_image' );
            if ( '' == $bg ) $bg = get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/bg_fusion.jpg';

            $slide_bg           = ( $slide_bg_url = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_et_slide_bg', true ) ) && '' != $slide_bg_url ? $slide_bg_url : $bg;

            $slide_subtitle     = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_et_slide_subtitle', true );
            $slide_more_text    = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_et_slide_more_text', true );
            $slide_more_link    = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_et_slide_more_link', true );
            $more_link          = '' != $slide_more_link ? $slide_more_link : get_permalink();
    ?>
        <div class="et-slide"<?php if ( '' != $slide_bg ) echo ' style="background-image: url(' . esc_url( $slide_bg ) . ');"'; ?>>
            <div class="container clearfix">
                <div class="description">
                    <h2><a href="<?php echo esc_url( $more_link ); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <?php if ( '' != $slide_subtitle ) { ?>
                    <p class="subtitle"><?php echo esc_html( $slide_subtitle ); ?></p>
                <?php } ?>

                    <p><?php truncate_post( 180 ); ?></p>

                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $more_link ); ?>" class="more">
                        <?php if ( '' != $slide_more_text ) echo esc_html( $slide_more_text ); else esc_html_e( 'Read More', 'Fusion' ); ?>
                    </a>
                </div> <!-- .description -->

            <?php
                $width = (int) apply_filters( 'slider_image_width', 535 );
                $height = (int) apply_filters( 'slider_image_height', 572 );
                $title = get_the_title();
                $thumbnail = get_thumbnail( $width, $height, '', $title, $title, false, 'Featured' );
                $thumb = $thumbnail["thumb"];
            ?>
                <div class="featured-image">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php print_thumbnail( $thumb, $thumbnail["use_timthumb"], $title, $width, $height, '' ); ?></a>
                </div> <!-- .featured-image -->
            </div> <!-- .container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the specified link within the featured-image in the last part of your snippet. You'll have to update `the_permalink()` with your custom link, too:

```
<div class="featured-image">
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $more_link ); ?>"><?php print_thumbnail( $thumb, $thumbnail["use_timthumb"], $title, $width, $height, '' ); ?></a>
</div> <!-- .featured-image -->
```